# Possible to replace WP includes directory?

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing some errors in WP includes... It's possible to replace it with Wordpress default WP includes using ftp without facing errors right?

Comment: I recommend doing a full manual update of WP installation :)

Comment: I would advice to include some code or extra information into your question, such as which errors are you having. It will increase the chances of you getting help and reduce the chances of having your questions flagged and removed.